# Error: List index out of range in game code

Tags: python

I'm having trouble with a list index error, the code may not be the sharpest. But I only know so much about coding in python, but I know enough to code a game.

The code that the function are used in:

```
#Checks if the move counter is more than 3, if it is, the player gets to decide what he/she wants to do
    if Moves != 0:
        Do = input('What do you do? Help to see all commands ')

        #Tests for if the player wants a magic spell
        if Do == 'Magic':
            if Moves == 3:
                ListToDo = MagicDmg(ListToDo, Moves)
                if ListToDo[0] == 'Ice' or 'Fire' or 'Bolt':
                    Mana = CheckMagicCost1(ListToDo, Mana, Moves)
                else:
                    Moves = Moves - 1
            elif Moves == 2:
                ListToDo = MagicDmg(ListToDo, Moves)
                Mana = CheckMagicCost2(ListToDo, Mana, Moves)
                Moves = Moves - 1
            else:
                ListToDo = MagicDmg(ListToDo, Moves)
                Mana = CheckMagicCost3(ListToDo, Mana, Moves)
                Moves = Moves - 1

#This function does not handle damage
def MagicDmg(ListToDo, Moves):
    print('Which magic? Ice, Fire or Bolt')
    MagicDo = input()
    if MagicDo != 'Ice' or 'Fire' or 'Bolt':
        if MagicDo == 'Ice':
            ListToDo.append('Ice')
        elif MagicDo == 'Fire':
            ListToDo.append('Fire')
        elif MagicDo == 'Bolt':
            ListToDo.append('Bolt')
    else:
        LIstToDo.remove(MagicDo)
        print('That is not a valid spell')
        Moves = Moves + 1
    return(ListToDo)

#Subtracts the mana cost of spells from mana
def CheckMagicCost1(ListToDo, Mana, Moves):
    if ListToDo[0] and Mana >= 10 == 'Ice':
        Mana = Mana - 10
    elif ListToDo[0] and Mana >= 15 == 'Fire':
        Mana = Mana - 15
    elif ListToDo[0] and Mana >= 25 == 'Bolt':
        Mana = Mana - 25
    else:
        print('You do not have enough Mana')
        Moves = Moves + 1
    return(Mana)

def CheckMagicCost2(ListToDo, Mana, Moves):
    if ListToDo[1] and Mana >= 10 == 'Ice':
        Mana = Mana - 10
    elif ListToDo[1] and Mana >= 15 == 'Fire':
        Mana = Mana - 15
    elif ListToDo[1] and Mana >= 25 == 'Bolt':
        Mana = Mana - 25
    else:
        print('You do not have enough Mana')
        Moves = Moves + 1
    return(Mana)

def CheckMagicCost3(ListToDo, Mana, Moves):
    if ListToDo[2] and Mana > 9 == 'Ice':
        Mana = Mana - 10
    elif ListToDo[2] and Mana > 14 == 'Fire':
        Mana = Mana - 15
    elif ListToDo[2] and Mana > 24 == 'Bolt':
        Mana = Mana - 25
    else:
        print('You do not have enough Mana')
        Moves = Moves + 1
    return(Mana)
```

The result:

```
A Azure Drake appeared! With 500 HP!

HP = 250 Mana = 250
Moves left: 3 

Boss's HP: 500 

What do you do? Help to see all commands Magic
Which magic? Ice, Fire or Bolt
i (False spell)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\Battle Test V2.py", line 186, in <module>
    if ListToDo[0] != 'Ice' or 'Fire' or 'Bolt':
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Please edit with the full error code.

Comment: Thanks mu 無 for editing my functions into the script

Comment: if ListToDo[0] and Mana >= 10 == 'Ice': you (mayba) want to say if len(ListToDo) >0 for the first par; for the second, I can't guess. Mana is a number or a string?

Comment: Please, Post your error message!!

Comment: Mana is an int: 250 aprox. Eric Levieil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't immediately tell if this is your only problem, but this line will definitely *not* work.

```
if MagicDo != 'Ice' or 'Fire' or 'Bolt':
```

What that really is checking is the following:

```
if (MagicDo != 'Ice') or ('Fire' != None) or ('Bolt' != None):
```

A possible fix for this is changing to this:

```
if MagicDo in(['Ice','Fire','Bolt']):
```

This will check if `MagicDo` is one of the three spells you want.  Again, I'm not sure if this is your only problem, but it's definitely a problem.

EDIT: I'm also noticing a problem in your `CheckMagicCost` functions.  None of your conditionals will do what you want them to do.  for example, the line

```
if ListToDo[0] and Mana >= 10 == 'Ice':
```

is really checking the following

```
if (ListToDo[0] != None) and ((Mana >= 10) == 'Ice'):
```

I'm guessing what you want is something more like the following:

```
if ListToDo[0] == 'Ice' and Mana >= 10:
```

This change should be propagated out to the rest of your conditionals in the `CheckMagicCost1`, `CheckMagicCost2`, and `CheckMagicCost3` functions.

Comment: Thanks Brien, I will try it in my code. From what I've tested that seems to be the only problem in the script so far. Before I got to this state in my code there were some errors, but mostly just coding errors like forgetting things.

Answer (score 0):

Without the error code there's not much to go on, but my gut feeling is you are going to run into trouble with these kinds of statements in your functions:

```
if ListToDo[1]
```

Might be better to wrap in a try block and catch the IndexError? Just a thought

```
try:
    #code
except IndexError:
    #contingency plan
```

Comment: Thanks, this will help me with other code projects in the future